# Hibernate : delete parent not referenced by children

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I need to delete a parent when there are no children that reference it. Is this possible in Hibernate? (actually I'm using fluent nhibernate but I presume the answer is the same)

e.g. I have many customers from different different companies. when I delete the last customer for a company I want to automatically delete the company details too.

Unlike a normal parent-child relationship, I don't consciously select to delete the company. as far as the user is concerned he's just deleting a customer; deleting an unreferenced company is just a by-product of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate won't do it magically for you. You'll have to implement it yourself:

```
Company company = customer.getCompany();
company.removeCustomer(customer);
session.delete(customer);
if (company.getCustomers().isEmpty()) {
    session.delete(company);
}
```

Comment: @Andy: And additionally "Company" could have other links, like "Building", for example. You should break such links manually too if you want to delete "Company".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this via NHibernate mappings, you will probably need to write some logic in your delete customer logic which counts the number of records in the customer table with the company identifier where the customer identifier is not the one being deleted and if the resulting count is 0, delete the customer and the company.

psudo code:

```
public void Delete(Customer customer)
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        int remainingCustomers = 
            session.Query<Customer>(c => c.CompanyId == customer.CompanyId && c.CustomerId != customer.CustomerId).Count();

        session.Delete(customer);

        if (remainingCustomers == 0)
        {
            session.Delete(customer.Company);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the delete doesn't need to happen instantly, you could run a stored procedure on a schedule to "tidy up" old companies.